# a daily time series - calculating totals in R

Tags: r

I have a time series with 30 years of daily data ( two columns labelled date and value)

```
Date        Value
01-01-1975  0.051
02-01-1975  0.051
03-01-1975  0.051
04-01-1975  0.051
05-01-1975  0.051
06-01-1975  0.051
07-01-1975  0.051
08-01-1975  0.051
09-01-1975  0.051
10-01-1975  0.048
11-01-1975  0.048
12-01-1975  0.048
.........
```

I am  trying to aggregate 5 days totals into sum ( so for each year I would get 73 values generated, it is a leap year then it would last value would be 6 days total rather than 5 days) In other words I always want to start on January 1 and always end on 31 Dec for each year, but I  need to deal with the leap year case somehow, e.g. by treating each year separately or by finding leap years and treating them differently. But I am having issues

I did the following,

```
test <- read.csv("~/H/x.csv")
test$Date <- as.Date(test$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
output <- aggregate(Flow ~ cut(Date, "5 days"), test, sum)
```

But it didn't quite gave me the results I wanted, which is for each year i want 73 values computed..

This is my first go at programming and R, so your guidance would be most welcome

Comment: So for leap years you want the last group to be six days, ie Dec 26 to Dec 31 to be one group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut` by 5 days but use `ave` to do it by year so that weeks do not cross year boundaries.  This gives `Date5`.  Now `aggregate` over the cut values:

```
# test data
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1975-01-01"), length = 2000, by = "day"), 
                 Value = 1:2000)

to.yr <- function(x) as.numeric(format(x, "%Y"))

Date5 <- ave(DF$Date, to.yr(DF$Date), FUN = function(x) cut(x, "5 day"))
ag <- aggregate(Value ~ Date5, DF, sum)
```

To count the number of weeks (full or partial) used:

```
> table(to.yr(ag$Date5))

1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 
  73   74   73   73   73   35
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  this is the closest what i need. I really appreciation all of your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data to play with:

```
test = data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1975-01-01"),as.Date("2005-01-01"),1))
test$value = runif(nrow(test))
head(test)
        Date     value
1 1975-01-01 0.2929824
2 1975-01-02 0.2222665
3 1975-01-03 0.2659065
4 1975-01-04 0.5511573
```

Now use `lubridate` package's `yday` function to set the day of year from 1 to 366:

```
> require(lubridate)
> test$yday = yday(test$Date)
```

Now integer divide year day minus 1 by five to give our grouping (from 0 to 73 in this case):

```
> test$grp = (test$yday-1) %/% 5
head(test,10)
         Date      value yday grp
1  1975-01-01 0.29298243    0   0
2  1975-01-02 0.22226646    1   0
3  1975-01-03 0.26590648    2   0
4  1975-01-04 0.55115730    3   0
5  1975-01-05 0.55990854    4   0
6  1975-01-06 0.70054357    5   1
7  1975-01-07 0.27184097    6   1
8  1975-01-08 0.47779337    7   1
9  1975-01-09 0.09127241    8   1
10 1975-01-10 0.65023465    9   1
```

So we have the odd days in each year in group 73. Which ones?

```
test[test$grp==73,]
            Date     value yday grp
731   1976-12-31 0.6636329  365  73
2192  1980-12-31 0.4586537  365  73
3653  1984-12-31 0.3473794  365  73
5114  1988-12-31 0.9160449  365  73
6575  1992-12-31 0.3215585  365  73
8036  1996-12-31 0.1965876  365  73
9497  2000-12-31 0.6795412  365  73
10958 2004-12-31 0.3622685  365  73
```

We want to put these in group 72:

```
test$grp[test$grp==73]=72
```

Now we can do an analysis based on that group variable, and we should only get 73 values (remember we started at zero). I'll use `dplyr` because its cool:

```
require(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean=mean(value))
Source: local data frame [73 x 2]

   grp      mean
1    0 0.5052336
2    1 0.5178286
3    2 0.4844037
4    3 0.5368534
5    4 0.4900208
6    5 0.5078784
7    6 0.4754043
....
```

73 x 2 looks right!

Comment: thank you very much. but when i tried this method I didn't get the desired results. your support is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What desired results? Did you want the sum over groups? Then `sum=sum(value)` in the `summarise` will do that. I was showing how to do any aggregated analysis over `grp` with `dplyr`.

Comment: I will try your method again ..as a I mentioned I am now learning R ..and it my first programming language..so i still struggling with the syntax and packages..so i am sorry